# To prove equality of two function definitions inductively

Tags: haskell, induction, equational-reasoning

How do I do the induction to establish the statement `moll n = doll n`, with

```
moll 0 = 1                               --(m.1)
moll n = moll ( n-1) + n                 --(m.2)

doll n = sol 0 n                         --(d.1)
 where
  sol acc 0 = acc +1                     --(d.2)
  sol acc n = sol ( acc + n) (n-1) -- ?    (d.2)
```

I tried to prove the base case for n = 0

```
doll 0 = (d.2) = 1 = (m.1) = moll 0 , which is correct.
```

Now for `n+1`, show that

```
moll 2n = doll (n + 1)

=> doll (n + 1) = (d.2) = soll (acc + n + 1) n
```

But what now? How can I simplify it any further?

Comment: You may need to generalize the statement so that in involves `sol`. Something like `sol acc n = ... something using moll, acc, n`. Once you prove that by induction, you can set `acc=0` so that the LHS reduces to `doll n` and hopefully the RHS reduces to `moll n`, proving the original goal.

Comment: I know it's probably not the way it's meant to but in this case I would rather proof that `mol n = 1 + sum [1..n] = doll n` which seems to be easier (both seems to be trivial inductions on first glance)

Comment: Please fix the title.

Comment: btw: as chi hinted you probably want to proof `sol acc n = acc 1 + sum [1..n]` as a *lemma* for the second one

Comment: It pains me to admit it, but I've got the same problem with sol acc n = 1 + sum[1..n] .
sol acc 0 = 1 = 1+ sum [1..n] is okay I guess. But how do i prove sol( acc n+n1) n = 1+ sum [1..n+1]?

Comment: Any particular reason you're ignoring the answer, and continuing here in the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a mistake in your `n+1` step. I suspect this is because you're new to Haskell and its precedence rules.

`moll (n+1)` is not, as you write `moll 2n` - I'm assuming that by that you mean `moll (2*n)`, since `moll 2n` is a haskell syntax error.

In any case, `moll (n+1)` is in fact `moll n + n + 1`, or, with extra parentheses added just to be explicit:

```
(moll n) + (n + 1)
```

That is, you apply `moll` to `n` and then you add `n + 1` to the result of that.

From here you should be able to apply the induction hypothesis and go forward.

---

More explicitly, since you seem to still be having trouble:

```
moll (n+1) == (moll n) + (n + 1)       (by m.2)
           == (doll n) + (n + 1)       (by induction hypot.)
           == (sol 0 n) + (n + 1)      (by d.1)
```

Now, as a lemma:

```
sol x n == (sol 0 n) + x
```

This can be proved by induction on `n`. It's obviously true for `n` equal to 0.

For the lemma's induction step:

```
sol x (n+1) == (sol (x + (n+1)) n)       (By d.2, for (n+1) > 0)
            == (sol 0 n) + (x + (n+1))   (By the induction hypot.)
            == (sol 0 n) + (n+1) + x     (This is just math; re-arranging)
            == ((sol 0 n) + (n+1)) + x
            == (sol (n+1) n) + x         (By the induction hypot. again)
            == (sol 0 (n+1)) + x         (By d.2 again)
```

That second time I used the induction hypothesis may seem a bit odd, but remember that the induction hypothesis says:

```
 sol x n == (sol 0 n) + x
```

*For all `x`*. Therefore, I can apply it to anything added to `(sol 0 n)`, including `n+1`.

Now, back to the main proof, using our lemma:

```
moll (n+1) == (sol 0 n) + (n + 1)      (we had this before)
           == sol (n+1) n              (by our lemma)
           == sol 0 (n+1)              (by d.2)
           == doll (n+1)               (by d.1)
```

Comment: thank you for all. It is helping me quit a lot. unfortunately I'm a real blockhead today. I really dont know how to prove sol x (n+1) == (sol 0 n) + x ? How can I rewrite it, to use  induction hypothesis?

Comment: You don't. You prove that `sol x (n+1)` is equal to `(sol 0 (n+1)) + x`. Remember to substitute `n+1` in for `n` wherever it is.

(See also the updated answer)

Comment: thank you for your patience. without your help, i couldn't possibly grapped the concept